# Memory error when open big gml

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a `gml` file(~20mb) of 90.000 nodes and 200.000 edges. For each node there is an `id` and the `label` which is 12 character string. I want to open this graph with `networkx` but returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 166, in <module>
    G = nx.read_gml('mygraph.gml', relabel = True)
  File "<string>", line 2, in read_gml
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py", line 263, i
n _open_file
    result = func(*new_args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\gml.py", line 85, in re
ad_gml
    G=parse_gml(lines,relabel=relabel)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\gml.py", line 173, in p
arse_gml
    G.add_edge(source,target,attr_dict=vdict)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\multigraph.py", line 261,
 in add_edge
    keydict={key:datadict}
MemoryError
```

Is this because these is not much memory? Could you please someone make a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `read_gml('mygraph.gml', relabel = False)`. If the memory error occurs again then you will be sure that the `networkx.read_gml` function can not be applied on GML file of more than 90.000 nodes and 200.000 edges.

An alternative can be [graph-tool](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/quickstart.html#graph-i-o), to try.